# P2P file sharing in JS

Tags: javascript, p2p, serverless

I received a requirement in which 
--I have to share files (PDF, Txt, Images) from one client to another client without any central server in between which saves the documents.

--User does not want to have any IAM in place so machines have to be identified by Clients IP address or any other unique ID of System on which application is installed.

I do not have any clue how to do this, Till now my research has pointed towards WebRTC, but I also came to know that using WebRTC for file sharing is dangerous as it may loose some data.

I need help in 
--understanding from scratch and how should I start tackling this challenge from ground to up.

So If someone can please explain the full process of setting up direct client to client connection till encrypted file sharing will be very helpful.

Comment: for starter, I think you might want to look at this https://www.npmjs.com/package/filepizza

Comment: Take a look at ***dat protocol***

Comment: Take a look at Gun.js

Answer (score 1):

> Till now my research has pointed towards WebRTC

Use TCP connections (or reliable transports built on top of UDP), they provide far more control and flexbility than WebRTC. They are available in nodejs environments. Browsers are inadequate for building truly distributed systems and other network programming tasks since they do not provide access to the whole network stack.